# Inverted pitch axis for flying only in Space engineers?

Tags: space-engineers

In Space engineers, the pitch (lean forward\backwards) is controlled by only one setting, both for flight and for walking, but not separate. This annoys me as I am used to have them separate in for example the battlefield games. I have looked trough all menus, but no sign of a separator. So I am wondering, via mod or .ini file (or whatever file that is used), can I separate the two, inverting pitch ONLY for flight?

*Note: This is a early access\beta stage game, so I know a setting like this COULD show up down the line, but right now, there is none that I know of.*

Answer (score 2):

It's a really wonky way to do it but you could assign pitch override on the gyroscope to your quickbar when you're in the pilot seat.  But that would mean turning would be assigned to a number instead of using your mouse. 
A dumb way to do it but it'd work.

Comment: The idea gives the possibility, but I gave it a test-run on my slowest ship, and even then it was really, really clunky to even try to make it go somewhat well. It certainly does not provide any smooth accuracy if I want to assault a ship or something, sadly. Maybe if I practiced a lot, but in the end, it's a lot quicker to just go into the menu and put the inversion setting on\off as needed... Fair idea, tho!

Comment: Yeah, hopefully they just add the option in the future